# Error while adding user to SharePoint group using CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

I'm facing error while trying to add users into the SharePoint groups using CSOM.
When I try to add user by passing user name as "`domain\V*****`" (all users start with "v" character), it through error as "\v" is hexadecimal value which can't pass.

Also I tried again by adding escape character like @domain\v******, but no luck..

But I tried the code with some test users like "domain\user1" which is working fine.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Are you trying to add all users under the domain? You can't pass wild card characters

Comment: @AmalHashim No, I'm trying to add single user only.. All username starts with V***** like ID..

Comment: Can you post code you tried?

Comment: should be `@"domain\victor"` or `"domain\\victor"` with two slashes

Answer (score 0):

I use the code bellow, but like Mike said maybe the key is to provide the string like "domain\user":

```
UserCreationInformation uci = new UserCreationInformation();
uci.Title = "John Lennon";
uci.Email = "jlennon@thebeatles.com";
uci.LoginName = "thebeatles\\jlennon";

Web web = ctx.Web;
GroupCollection groupcoll = web.SiteGroups;
string grouptitle = "My Group";
ctx.Load(web, w => w.SiteGroups);
ctx.Load(groupcoll, grps => grps.Include(g => g.Title).Where(g => g.Title == grouptitle));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Group group = null;

User member = web.EnsureUser(uci.Email);
ctx.Load(member, m => m.LoginName, m => m.Title);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

uci.Title = member.Title;
uci.LoginName = member.LoginName;

if (groupcoll.Count > 0)
{
    group = groupcoll.FirstOrDefault();
    User addeduser = group.Users.Add(uci);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```